# Cannot install Android Studio on Chrome OS: Error while installing package: package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm64)

Tags: android, android-studio, google-chrome-os, androidappsonchromeos

I cant seem to install Android Studio on my Chromebook and I cant find a compatible package on the website. Any way to get it working on this specific Chromebook? (Acer Chromebook Spin 513)

About Chrome OS:

```
Google Chrome   90.0.4430.218 (Official Build) (32-bit)
Revision    3d6fce300d32b4652aed6bfe358eba932e094ee5-refs/branch-heads/4430@{#1466}
Platform    13816.82.0 (Official Build) stable-channel trogdor
Firmware Version    Google_Lazor.13577.102.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just install the .DEB file. You also need to make sure you have 3-4 gb enabled for linux. I had the same problem, and it turns out I was not allocating enough storage to actually install android studio.

Answer (score 0):

First, add the Linux terminal. Then install snap or flatpak in the terminal. Then, use snap or flatpak to install Android Studio without errors. Snap and flatpak will find which architecture your computer is and will install the Android Studio designed for the architecture

Snap : https://snapcraft.io/android-studio

Flatpak : https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.google.AndroidStudio